# MYSQL select recursivo entre 2 tablas?

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos tablas (examen) y (nota) que están relacionadas entre si por la columna "id" de la tabla (examen) y la columna "id_examen" de la tabla (nota).

Quiero obtener la media de las notas por cada examen.

Por ejemplo, del examen con id=1 -> "Test sorpresa" en la tabla (examen), quiero obtener la media de todos los registros de la tabla (nota) que tengan como id_examen=1.

```
TABLA EXAMEN

    id  |  nombre                      |   fecha          |    id_perfil
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   | 'Test sorpresa'              | '2018-04-21'     |       '1'
    2   | 'Evaluación 1º trimestre'    | '2018-11-25'     |       '1'
    3   | 'Fichas de grafomotricidad'  | '2018-10-15'     |       '1'

TABLA NOTA

id   | valor |  id_examen
------------------------
1    | 5     |  1
1    | 6     |  1
1    | 8     |  1
1    | 4     |  2
1    | 8     |  2
```

Esta la consulta que estoy intentando:

```
SELECT t5.nombre, AVG(t3.valor) 
FROM examen as t5, (  SELECT t1.valor
                      FROM nota as t1 
                      WHERE t1.id_examen = t5.id
                   ) as t3
WHERE t5.id_perfil=1 ORDER BY t5.fecha DESC LIMIT
```

Pero me da este error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Quiero conseguir:

```
Test sorpresa 6,7

Evaluación 1º trimestre 6
```

Comment: da un error? a AVG(nota1.valor)  no le falta un as valor?

Comment: Antonio no se entiende del todo tu pregunta. ¿Cuál es la relación entre las tablas? ¿A qué corresponde la columna `id` en la tabla `NOTA` y como se relaciona esa columna con la tabla `EXAMEN`? ¿A qué corresponde la columna `id_perfil`? ¿Sirve para establecer algún tipo de relación?

Comment: @A.Cedano he reformulado la pregunta en el mensaje inicial.

Comment: @gbianchi ya le he agregado un as valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahora sí se entiende.

Puedes lograrlo simplemente con esta consulta, la cual no hace más que usar las columnas relacionadas en ambas tablas para hacer un `JOIN`.

#### Si quieres el average de cada id de examen

Combinas `AVG` con un `GROUP BY` de este modo:

```
SELECT 
    e.nombre, 
    AVG(n.valor) average
FROM examen e
INNER JOIN nota n ON e.id=n.id_examen 
GROUP BY e.id
ORDER BY e.fecha DESC;
```

**Resultado:**

```
nombre                         average
-----------------------------------------------
Evaluación 1º trimestre        6,0000
Test sorpresa                  6,3333
```

---

#### Filtrando por un examen en específico

Casi la misma consulta, pero cambiando el `GROUP BY` por un `WHERE`.

```
SELECT 
    e.nombre, 
    AVG(n.valor) average
FROM examen e
INNER JOIN nota n ON e.id=n.id_examen
WHERE e.id=1;
```

El resultado sería:

```
nombre              average
-------------------------------
Test sorpresa       6,3333
```

---

### Prueba de concepto

Aquí puedes ver un <kbd>**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/LNA92486)**</kbd> y hacer pruebas con datos reales.

Comment: Realmente lo que yo quiero es que me saque las medias de todos los examenes, no solo de uno. Además cada día se irán agregando nuevos exámenes por lo que no puedo especificar el id del examen en la consulta.

Comment: @AntonioRuiz en ese caso puedes agrupar por cada id de examen mediante `GROUP BY` y te arrojará los promedios de todos los exámenes. Revisa la respuesta editada.

Comment: Perfecto, que maravilla. Gracias.